# How to filter the object what we want from json data..?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-filter

I am getting the response from backend, it return the json data.

But I need to pass the object separately to "`handlebars.js`" - templates.

In this case, how do I iterate the json response and filter the data what I want?

My sample data :

```
{
    "username":"xxxx",
    "name":"yyyyy",
    "allLocales":[
        {           "name":"Afrikaans"
        },
        {           "name":"Albanian"
        }           "name":"Arabic"

    ],
    "userLocales":[
        {           "name":"English (US)"
        },
        {           "name":"Swedish"
        }

],
    "message":"New massage will be here"
}
```

How can I get the `var username = {"username":"xxxx"}`, and

```
var nantions = "allLocales":[
            {           "name":"Afrikaans"
            },
            {           "name":"Albanian"
            }           "name":"Arabic"

        ]
```

and like so..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a method to easy parse your data.

with `hasOwnProperty`

Fiddle : [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eU3Gu/)

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the respective part of the object created by the JSON.

```
var nantions = jsonObj[ 'allLocales' ];
```

If you need to parse the JSON beforehand, use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse( json );
```

**EDIT**

If you need the `username` really as an object, I think you are left with this:

```
var username = { 'username': jsonObj['username'] };
```

Comment: But what about the user name..?

Comment: are you familiar with handlebars.js ..?

Comment: @3gwebtrain Nope. But is there any problem passing too many variables to a template?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the properties of an object with a simple dot-notation:

```
objectName.propertyName
```

For example, in your case

```
var username = obj.username;   // xxxx
var nantions = obj.allLocales;   // array of Object
```

More details here: [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/anCK7/)

Answer (score 0):

first please assign the sample data to a variable

```
var json_test = {
"username":"xxxx",
"name":"yyyyy",
"allLocales":[
    {           "name":"Afrikaans"
    },
    {           "name":"Albanian"
    },
    {   "name":"Arabic"
    }

],
"userLocales":[
    {           "name":"English (US)"
    },
    {           "name":"Swedish"
    }
```

],
    "message":"New massage will be here"
};

after this if you want to access username the you should write like this

```
var username = json_test['username'];

var nantions = json_test['allLocales'];
```

Comment: username getting the value.. but i need the object